# Basis of two props wanted to update single state value without useEffect

Tags: reactjs

What is the best way to update single state value, if specific two props changes, without useEffect, since performance point of view we should not be setting state inside useEffect.

For Example:

```
const NestedList = ({childItems, parentItems, selected, ...rest}) => {
  const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState({}); //assume this could be hash object 
  
  // Wrong X
  useEffect(() => setCurrentItems(parentItems), [parentItems])

  // Wrong X
  useEffect(() => setCurrentItems(childItems), [childItems])

  return ...
```

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with setting state inside an effect, you just need to be careful not to create circular logic (Not that you necessarily need an effect or a state in this example)

Answer (score 0):

React component updates on both State change and Prop change. So you don't have to do anything additonal

Comment: thanks reply. Yes you are right, but what i wanted im constructing JSX based on single state value which is depend on two props, then whats best way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Try below in single use effect. You can also compare previous props with new props.

useEffect(() => {
setCurrentItems(whateverthevalueis)
}, [prop1,prop2]);

Comment: Thanks for reply, this way we can easily do it, but i dot want to use useEffect just to set the state value.

Comment: its not against the practice to do that buddy

Comment: Yes you are totally right, but we should ONLY use useEffect for 3rd party/system interaction NOT for setting up the component state. So i just need to understand other possible ways of handling above use case. :) But any way u can use useEffect for setting up state if anyone want!

Answer (score 0):

What i try to figure out is the `why` in this case.
Why do you need a state if you always want to change it?
Why do the two props replace each other in the state?

There is nothing wrong with setting the state in a useEffect as alot of people already have said. However useEffect should be used for side effects.

There is no golden solution for all cases.

Use a state if you set the intial state with props and then the component update the state itself.

```js
const processItems = (childItems, parentItems, ) => {
    // Do what you want to create one state
    return childItems 
}

const NestedList = ({childItems, parentItems, selected, ...rest}) => {
    // use props to set the inital state
    const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState(processItems(childItems, parentItems))
    // We can later mutate the state, however if the props change we do not care
```

If the parent always pass the state as a prop, you do not need a state since the state is handled higher up.

```js
const NestedList = ({childItems, parentItems, selected, ...rest}) => {
    // No need for a state here, we can just use the props directly and
    // the parent will pass the updated props when the state changes
```

If the parent pass several props and you need to calculate stuff based on the props, use memo hook.

```js
const NestedList = ({childItems, parentItems, selected, ...rest}) => {
  
  const currentItems = useMemo(() => {
    // Add the condition of what items to show here 
    if(parentItems.length > 0) return parentItems
    return childItems
  }, [childItems,parentItems])

  return ...
```

Comment: Thanks, i think you got my point and may be thats one way of handling prop change. Why i'm insisting not to use useEffect is that most of developer use useEffect just for setting up state, if your app grows they ended up having multiple useEffects, and ultimately it's very hard to keep track of your code. So just wanted to understand best possible use cases for this!

Comment: There will never be a catch all solution and you should write the code for what you need. Its good to try to limit the amount os useEffect hooks, but you should also ask yourself if a state is needed. Will the component change the state, if not dont use a state. I have updated my answer